# CoordinatorLayout Custom Behavior with LinearLayout as child

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, coordinator-layout

I want to implement a custom behavior on LinearLayout.
This is the structure of my xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.../>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.../>
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="com.xxx.BottomBarBehavior"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal".../>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The LinearLayout is inside CoordinatorLayout, below the DrawerLayout.
The LinearLayout is not moving up when the snackbar is shown. I just can't get my head around it. The layout is such that the DrawerLayout contains a ViewPager and this viewPager is populated by another xml by a fragment. And the snackbar is generated by an element in the recyclerView of this fragment.

This is how my BottomBarBehavior custom behavior class looks like:

```
public class BottomBarBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<LinearLayout> {
public BottomBarBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {}

@Override
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, LinearLayout child, View dependency) {
    return ( dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout ) ||
            ( dependency instanceof DrawerLayout );
}

@Override
public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, LinearLayout child, View dependency) {
    if( dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout ) {
        float translationY = Math.min(0, dependency.getTranslationY() - dependency.getHeight());
        child.setTranslationY(translationY);
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Clean and rebuild the project. Your `layoutDependsOn` has nothing to do with `ClassCastException`. Check if that happens again.

Comment: This worked! But my behavior is still not followed by LinearLayout.

Comment: What CoordinatorLayout instance are you passing to your Snackbar's make() call?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing a `super();` in the constructor of `BottomBarBehavior`.

Comment: Yes, I did miss it. But even after putting super(), it is still not working proper. The onDependentViewChanged() is simply not called when the snackbar is created.

Comment: The only other difference between my working implementation and yours: I don't check for `DrawerLayout` inside `layoutDependsOn`

Comment: But that shouldn't matter at all. Right?

Comment: Hmm.. I also have `android:id="@+id/snackbar"` in CoordinatorLayout and then to invoke it `Snackbar sb = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.snackbar), "D'oh", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);`

Comment: So your coordinatorLayout has the id 'snackbar'?

Comment: When I tried to do this, I couldn't see the snackbar itself.

Comment: My CoordinatorLayout is pretty simple: it contains only LinearLayout with few views/buttons. Other activity's layouts (listview etc.) are outside of it. That seems working for me. Also pls try to remove `DrawerLayout` from your behavior implementation and see if it helps (I see a problem in `onDependentViewChanged` when the method always returns true even when `dependency` is not of `Snackbar` type)

Comment: is there a way you could share your full xml file + calls to invoke `Snackbar`. I suspect that `BottomBarBehavior` wasn't even instantiated. I recommend to add logging in all behavior methods to check that. Did you define  `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`?

Comment: It is definitely instantiated because I am getting callbacks to onDependentViewChanged() on any change in DrawerLayouts.